# How can I configure my macOS Catalina installation to recognize, and use, the version 12.4 Mail.app used in macOS Mojave?

Tags: catalina, mail.app

The macOS Catalina Mail.app preferences panel has an option for selecting between the version 13.4 Mail.app (Catalina) and the version 12.4 Mail.app (Mojave).  With both versions of the Mail.app in the Catalina System Applications folder, I am unable get Catalina to launch the older version 12.4 Mail.app.  I'm sure it's a simple configuration issue.  I'd appreciate any guidance available.

Comment: I have an Apple installed (latest) version of macOS Catalina (10.15.7) and no such selection exists for me. It might be helpful for you to describe how to get to this preference or post a screen cap of what you are talking about. I have **never** seen such a thing and I've been using MacOS since the System 4 days...